# how can i synthesis unsaturated ester via wittig reaction?

Tags: wittig-reactions

What is the best pocedure to synthesis ethyl cinnamate using benzaldehyde and (carbethoxymethylene)triphenylphosphorane (wittig reagent) and chloroform as solvent via wittig reaction?

Comment: Why are you using chloroform as solvent? It precludes the use of strong bases.

Answer (score 1):

A good system for this is using DBU as the base in refluxing chloroform.  Bull. Chem. Soc. Japan (2003) **76** 1675